# scipy.test() results in errors

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

Having some problems with scipy. Installed latest version using pip (0.17.0). Run scipy.test() and I'm getting the following errors. Are they okay to ignore? I'm using python 2.7.6.

Thanks for your help.

> ======================================================================
>
> ### ERROR: test_add_function_ordered (test_catalog.TestCatalog)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/weave/tests/test_catalog.py", line 477, in test_add_function_ordered
>       q.add_function('f',string.upper)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/weave/catalog.py", line 833, in add_function
>       self.add_function_persistent(code,function)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/weave/catalog.py", line 849, in add_function_persistent
>       cat = get_catalog(cat_dir,mode)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/weave/catalog.py", line 486, in get_catalog
>       sh = shelve.open(catalog_file,mode)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 239, in open
>       return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 222, in **init**
>       import anydbm
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/anydbm.py", line 50, in 
>       _errors.append(_mod.error)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'error'
>
> ======================================================================
>
> ### ERROR: test_add_function_persistent1 (test_catalog.TestCatalog)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/weave/tests/test_catalog.py", line 466, in test_add_function_persistent1
>       q.add_function_persistent('code',i)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/weave/catalog.py", line 849, in add_function_persistent
>       cat = get_catalog(cat_dir,mode)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/weave/catalog.py", line 486, in get_catalog
>       sh = shelve.open(catalog_file,mode)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 239, in open
>       return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 222, in **init**
>       import anydbm
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/anydbm.py", line 50, in 
>       _errors.append(_mod.error)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'error'
>
> ======================================================================
>
> ### ERROR: test_get_existing_files2 (test_catalog.TestCatalog)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/weave/tests/test_catalog.py", line 394, in test_get_existing_files2
>       q.add_function('code', os.getpid)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/weave/catalog.py", line 833, in add_function
>       self.add_function_persistent(code,function)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/weave/catalog.py", line 849, in add_function_persistent
>       cat = get_catalog(cat_dir,mode)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/weave/catalog.py", line 486, in get_catalog
>       sh = shelve.open(catalog_file,mode)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 239, in open
>       return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 222, in **init**
>       import anydbm
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/anydbm.py", line 50, in 
>       _errors.append(_mod.error)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'error'
>
> ======================================================================
>
> ### ERROR: test_create_catalog (test_catalog.TestGetCatalog)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/weave/tests/test_catalog.py", line 286, in test_create_catalog
>       cat = catalog.get_catalog(pardir,'c')
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/weave/catalog.py", line 486, in get_catalog
>       sh = shelve.open(catalog_file,mode)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 239, in open
>       return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 222, in **init**
>       import anydbm
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/anydbm.py", line 50, in 
>       _errors.append(_mod.error)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'error'
>
> ---
>
> Ran 20343 tests in 138.416s
>
> FAILED (KNOWNFAIL=98, SKIP=1679, errors=4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these are in `weave`, which is not used anywhere else in scipy itself. So unless you're using weave directly, you're likely OK. And there is likely no reason to use weave in new code anyway.